# Opening CAP file in Python using Scapy libraries raises and exception

Tags: python, scapy, cap

I have a cap file that I want to read and process using python, I used the Scapy library but when trying to read it using the rdpcap function it raises an exception.
[CAP File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dvkixmxO7rVfdOiSeLVfxxWrTEqzSx4j/view?usp=sharing)
The full stacktrace:

```
Scapy_Exception                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-544e8f19828d> in <module>()
      1 file = '.....'
----> 2 packets = rdpcap(file)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/utils.py in rdpcap(filename, count)
   1115     # One day we should simplify this mess and use a much simpler
   1116     # layout that will actually be supported and properly dissected.
-> 1117     with PcapReader(filename) as fdesc:  # type: ignore
   1118         return fdesc.read_all(count=count)
   1119 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/utils.py in __call__(cls, filename)
   1170                 pass
   1171 
-> 1172         raise Scapy_Exception("Not a supported capture file")
   1173 
   1174     @staticmethod

Scapy_Exception: Not a supported capture file
```

Note: I have managed to open the cap file in Wireshark and export it to CSV, but I want to know if there is a way to solve this since I have a lot of files and it would be very convenient to open them directly using python.

EDIT 1: Updated cap file link.

Answer (score 0):

I can open cap files like this with scapy:

```py
from scapy.all import rdpcap, IP
for p in rdpcap('capfile.cap'):
    print(p[IP].src)
```

Comment: I doesn't work for me, can you please try with the file I provided, just to make sure if it's damaged?